# Which Java data structure should I use to input double values at given index without giving fixed size?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a dataset of `row_id`, `col_id` and `value` for entering into a matrix (ie. some 2D data structure), and these values are not given in a sorted order in the input.

eg.

```
1,1,0.3
4,1,0.5
2,3,0.4
```

and so on.

I do not know the maximum possible value of `row_ID` or `col_ID` so I cannot have a fixed size `array`. I thought of using an `ArrayList`, but since I need to enter the values into the `ArrayList` on any given index (say the row/column has not yet been initialized) I end up with some weird code, such that I have to create new rows for whenever that given row size isn't there.

```
public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context throws IOException, InterruptedException{

ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> vArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();

for(Text val : values){
String[] line = value.toString().split(",", 3);

int rowID = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
int colID = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
int value = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);

if(vArray.size() < rowID){                    //checking if this row already exists
for(int i=0; i < rowID; i++){
//add a row
ArrayList<Double> row = new ArrayList<Double>();
vArray.add(row);

    for(int j=0; j < colID; j++){
    //add a column
    vArray.get( array.size() -1 ).add( 1 );
    }
   }
}
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Also, I **think** that the `vArray.size()` doesn't give me the number of rows, but the number of columns in the `ArrayList`, but I want the number of rows, so is there a way to get that?

I am somewhat new to Java, so I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a java `HashMap` which behaves much like an associative array where you can have a key that is an Object and a value that is an Object as well. Check out [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)'s. There is also a `size` method on the `HashMap` which could be useful to you.

Comment: I don't want to use a Hashmap. I need to use a 2D array type structure. I guess I should have specified this.

Comment: What advantage would a 2d array structure give you? You can map to an array with a HashMap.

Comment: Oh, Is it possible to map to an array based on the composite index (row, column) in the Hashmap? If yes, then I can use that.

Comment: Actually I need to pass a reference to this array to another function, and that has already been written. So I am trying to get a workaround.

Comment: Im not sure if I know what you mean but if you had a Class Index with both row and column in it and defined the `.equals` function to just compare the row and column attributes you can key on the Index class to an array or value with a HashMap.

Comment: The downfall is that the size will only give back the number of indexes in the HashMap. You could just have a count that tallies the number of rows as you insert them into the HashMap or you could iterate the keys and find the largest row value in the Index objects

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes an array or `List` will be a very poor choice if the IDs are large, as you will be forced to allocate memory which is mostly wasted. The standard solution is to represent a sparse matrix as a map.

You can either have one big map, with (row,col) as a composite key mapping to the value. Or you can have a two-level map, where rows are mapped to other maps, which map columns to values. Without knowing much more about your constraints or purpose, it's hard to say more than just that.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using a map? I kind of need to use an array/2D array. Thank you.

Comment: Also, is there a way to get the no. of rows in this design?

Comment: In the question you acknowledge that you can't use an array, and say you don't want to write weird code related to a list. But now you say you have to use an array. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I mean ArrayList, or something similar. No fixed size array. I just meant 2D data structure. I'll probably convert from Hashmap to ArrayList